# Unit testing framework for C++ that doesn't need to preprocess the code

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, frameworks, c-preprocessor

There are several major unit tests frameworks, but as far as I know all of them needs to process the source code in some way.

For example, I am using cxxunit, and it requires the unit tests to be processed using some python script. The problem with this is that it increases the build time.

Does anyone know of a unit testing framework for C++ code that doesn't preprocess the unit tests code?

PS: I need it for linux, but it is ok if it is multi platform.

Comment: doh I can not believe that out of all unit testing frameworks out there we got stuck with one that requires preprocessing :(

Comment: Given C++' abysmal build times, is this preprocessing really relevant?

Comment: @sbi Yes, because I have lots of unit tests. Changing just one, it takes very long to preprocess them all (and my development machine is a beast). Without a need to preprocess, rebuilding unit tests would take almost instantly.

Comment: @sbi Forgot to add : TDD (or BDD) are not working very well if the unit tests recompilation takes long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [google test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) framework. You need just build library source code one time. Then you can create your tests as `.cpp` files, then compile and link them with `gtest` and needed project libraries as ordinary c++ sources.

Besides that, it is multiplatform.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Boost.Test`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/index.html). I've had good experiences with it. It does not require any special preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy with [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).

Answer (score 1):

[CPPUnit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/) is my personal choice at the moment, and is in plain C++.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using TestDog. You construct your tests using the code to test and it produces HTML output summaries.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend considering Andrew Marlow's FRUCTOSE http://fructose.sourceforge.net/ in your evaluation too... he's a very thorough and professional developer who compared existing offers carefully before crafting his own.  See also an ACCU article disucssing the library: http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1305

Comment: Thanks. I have been following his posts on clc++, and doubt he did it wrongly.

Comment: I just checked it, and it has a python script to generate the main() for unit tests. That is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: VJo: oh dear... I'm sure he had his reasons, but can well understand that could be a show stopper in your situation.  Sorry for not checking on that myself....